# Making Craft\DateTime Object from string in Twig

Tags: plugin-development, templating, datetime

I'm trying to use Craft's native datepicker with a plugin I've made for the admin section.

I've got some code that works;

```
{% from "_includes/forms" import date %}

<h3>Start Date</h3>

{{ date({
    id: 'startDate',
    name: 'startDate',
    value: now
}) }}
```

but I can't seem to get it to work with any other date, no matter what I do.

In my URL I have;

```
startDate=09/02/2017
```

and in my twig template I have;

```
{% set startDate = craft.request.getParam('startDate') %}
```

What do I need to do to `startDate` in order to get the date picker to read that date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieved this by putting this into my variables file;

```
public function craftDate($date) {

     $dateObject = DateTime::createFromString($date,craft()->timezone);

     return $dateObject;

 }
```

and then calling this in my template by using;

```
{{ date({
    id: 'startDate',
    name: 'startDate',
    value: craft.formExport.craftDate(reconfiguredStartDate)
}) }}
```

(The date had been reconfigured from 01/02/2017 to 2017-02-01)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, what you're trying to do, is not possible without writing a simple plugin to return a `Craft\DateTime` object that the day picker can work with.

The global variable `now`, is a `Craft\DateTime` object, which the date picker is happy to work with because it can call `localeDate()` on it.

However, anything returned by `date` or `date_modify` twig filters, will be a `\DateTime` object, which lacks functionality that the date picker relies on.

Your only option would be, to create a simple plugin that can take your date parameter, and return a `Craft\DateTime` object, which you can pass as a `value` to the date picker/date macro.

This is one of those things that you think, *"this should be easy or at least possible"*, but I haven't found a *twig-only* solution yet.

Comment: This is one of the main reasons (along with about 100 others), that we've ditched the `Craft\DateTime` class in Craft 2 and are just using PHP's native DateTime everywhere in Craft 3.

Comment: @BradBell Craft 3 FTW:)

Answer (score 0):

The [Twig Perversion](https://github.com/marionnewlevant/craft-twig_perversion) plugin has a `date_from_string` filter that turns a string into a `Craft\DateTime` object.